# Why do these for and while loops iterate differently?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I have a question about the for and while loop in Python3.6:

Why variables within the while loop can effect this loop, and variables within the for loop cannot? Is there a way to make the latter way work as well?

I am doing a math question using Python to calculate, the algorithm uses a for loop same as the first one in the code blocks.
But with the value of variable-a in this loop changing, the for-loop's range  stays.

So I uses a while loop to achieve my goal and it goes through.
My guess on this is that a range(a set of elements) is decided once it is been run, or a for-loop does not share the same 'nature' as a while-loop.

```
a = 28
for i in range(1,a):
    a = a - 5

# outcomes: a = -107, i =27

a = 28
i = 1
while i < a:
    a = a - 5
    i = i + 1

# outcomes: a = 3, i = 6
```

Comment: Yes, in the for loop, the range is precomputed, so the iterations fix. In the while loop, the condition is retested based on the values of `a` and `i` after each iteration.

Comment: You can add a print statement inside each loop to see @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer and Python loops in action.

Comment: Yes, python `for` loops are "for-each" constructs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 28
for i in range(1,a):
    a = a - 5
```

Read: *Subtract 5 from `a`, 27 times.*

---

```
a = 28
i = 1
while i < a:
    a = a - 5
    i = i + 1
```

Read: *Keep subtracting 5 from `a` as long as `i` is lesser than `a`.*

---

Obviously, these two statements are not the same. The `for` loop precomputes the range, and the iterations are fixed, regardless of the value of `a`. In the case of the `while`, the condition is retested with the latest value of `a` at each new iteration, accounting for the difference you see.

Comment: Sorry,new to stackoverflow. I thought upvoting means acceptance to the answer, just found out that theres a check mark beside the answer that needed be toggled. Thanks for the help!